# About the meaning of Friends' Chandler's quote, "then put out fire by peeing , no get invited back."

Tags: phrase-meaning

In S01, finale, Chandler and Joey enter Monica's apartment with charcoal to take part in a barbecue:

> Chandler: Men are here.
>
> Joey: We make fire. Cook meat.
>
> Chandler: Then put out fire
>   by peeing, **no get invited
>   back**.

What does the text in bold mean?

Comment: Chandler and Joey seem to be deliberately talking like incompetent non-native speakers. The highlighted "mock foreigner" text would have been something like *We will not get invited back*.

Comment: Is it about mocking foreigners? I would understand a non-native/foreigner would say something like, "no get invited back", but why would a foreigner put out a barbecue's fire by peeing? If it's just a joke, then what do foreigners have to do with it?

Comment: I have no idea why they're talking like that. You're the one reading/watching the thing! But please don't imagine you're learning "English" here.

Comment: Don't worry I'm not going to involve you in any further Friends stuff. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Respectfully, this isn't about non-native English speakers, it is about primitive characters.  They are mocking themselves, acting like boneheaded primitives.  Here is a write-up on the idiom: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Hulkspeak

Comment: @Mike Kozar: I suppose it's "PC" to insist that at the ***literal*** level they're parodying hypothetical English-speaking cavemen or fictitious mutant superheroes, rather than "xenophobically" alluding to nns in general (or stereotypical native Amerinds in particular). As to exactly who they might ***really*** be mocking (if indeed such a concept can be meaningfully applied), I don't have the odd weekend to spare, so I think I'll leave your tvtropes link unexplored and not watch the episode itself! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I believe you're using "PC" to imply that this is really a parody of non-native speakers, and the "caveman" theory is an excuse.  As this is a site for non-native speakers, I think it's important to be clear that as a native speaker I can definitively say this is NOT secretly mocking non-native speakers, any more than "HULK SMASH!" in The Avengers was intended to mock non-native speakers.  The joke is that the characters are so overcome with their own primitive manliness that they no longer understand grammar, or have enough decorum not to pee on the fire.

Answer (score 3):

They are mocking manly/macho/caveman speech, because they "brought the fire" (charcoal) for the BBQ. So the phrases are deliberately mis-formed.

Chandler's line says that if we take this manly-man stuff too far by peeing on the fire to put it out, then *we won't get invited back*.